# Change on laravel collection does not effect

Tags: php, laravel, collections, model, eloquent

I have a user model that it has a collection of posts.
I want to return a collection of users data with their's posts except an especial post for each user as json; for that I user this code:

```
$users=User::with('posts')->get();
foreach($users as $user){
    $user->posts=$user->posts->except($except_id);
    // $user->posts=null;// ->>> also this code does not work
}
return $users;
```

But in output users' posts are not changed!!!

**Edited:**

```
$except_id = $user->golden_post_id;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried some ways finally I found that `unset()` can solve the problem.

This code works:

```
$users=User::with('posts')->get();
foreach($users as $user){
    $posts=$user->posts->except($except_id);
    unset($user->posts);
    $user->posts=$post;
}
return $users;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do that as a query constraint in the `with` call instead, e.g. like this:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($query) use ($except_id) {
    $query->where('id', '!=', $except_id);
}])->get();
```

Now you get all posts for all users except the posts with the id of `$except_id`, and you don't have to go through them afterwards to sort them out.

Comment: Thank you. but `$except_id` comes from user model ( `$except_id = $user->golden_post_id` ). Is there a way for this?